# Laravel Validation Error Handing

Tags: php, laravel

I have a statement in my code like this

```
  return response()->json([
     'error'=>$validator->errors()->all()
  ]);
```

When I view the response it has curly braces around it and looks like an object and it throws an error in the console that says

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at parse ()

What do I need to change to get the format that my ajax call can interpret?

This code worked inside of a controller but when I move it to a different page it breaks so it seems there is something in the controller that corrects this, but is missing on my own page.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like below code

```
$data['success'] = false;
$data['message'] = $validator->errors()->all();
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: that did it! with the exception that I had to add to it $validator->errors()->all();

Answer (score 1):

obviously the json structure is wrong, u show use json_encode() to handle the $validator->errors()->all();

```
return response()->json([
 'error'=>json_encode($validator->errors()->all())
```

]);

Comment: thanks for this alternate idea. I clicked wrong button at first to downvote when I meant to upvote